# Comparing binary 0x and 0x00 turns out to be equal on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, varbinary

It seems that SQL Server considers 0x and 0x00 equal values:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 0x = 0x00 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

This outputs `1`.

**How can I get true binary bit-for-bit comparison behavior?** Also, what are the **exact rules** under which two `(var)binary` values are considered equal?

Also note the following behavior:

```
--prints just one of the values
SELECT DISTINCT [Data]
FROM (VALUES (0x), (0x00), (0x0000)) x([Data])

--prints the obvious length values 1, 2 and 3
SELECT DATALENGTH([Data]) AS [DATALENGTH], LEN([Data]) AS [LEN]
FROM (VALUES (0x), (0x00), (0x0000)) x([Data])
```

Background of the question is that I'm trying to deduplicate binary data. I need to `GROUP BY` binary data, not just compare two values. I'm glad I even noticed this problem.

Note, that `HASHBYTES` does not support LOBs. I'd also like to find a simpler solution.

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head.  There are really two comparisons that you are looking to do.  Value and data length.  0x0 is equal to 0x00, just like 0 (base 10) is equal to 00.  What's wrong with doing an extra text on DATALENGTH()?

Comment: @ThomasStringer 0x0 is different from 0x (the latter is an empty blob). Regarding DATALENGTH: I'm not sure what the comparison rules are. Is this *always* enough to guarantee equality? I can't guess here, must be correct. Also, it makes grouping on a blob impossible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is exactly analogous to the situation with string comparisons and trailing spaces but can't find any documentation that states that explicitly.

Comment: @MartinSmith Also there is no collation for blobs. `0x20 = 0x2020` is false, though. Trailing spaces are observed.

Comment: @usr - Yes, I said analogous. Not the same. When comparing strings it [pads with trailing spaces](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626). For binary I guess it pads with trailing null bytes.

Comment: [Invalid equality comparison for varbinary data with right padded zeros](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/734337/invalid-equality-comparison-for-varbinary-data-with-right-padded-zeros)

Comment: @MartinSmith I guess that documents the behavior if the issue is to be trusted. Using DATALENGTH it is now possible to compare and group safely. Care to add an answer? If not I'll add it myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't find this comparison behaviour specified anywhere in BOL.

But the Connect Item [Invalid equality comparison for varbinary data with right padded zeros](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/734337/invalid-equality-comparison-for-varbinary-data-with-right-padded-zeros) states that

> Basically, the standard leaves it up to implementation to treat
>   strings that differ only by [trailing] `00` as equal or less. We treat it as equal.

The Connect Item also states that the presence of trailing zeroes is the only case in which SQL Server differs from byte-by-byte comparison behavior.

In order to distinguish between two binary values in SQL Server that differ only by trailing `0x00` characters you can also add `DATALENGTH` into the comparison as indicated in your question.

The reason for preferring `DATALENGTH` rather than `LEN` generally here is because the latter gives an implicit cast to `varchar` and then you get the problem with trailing spaces.

```
+-------------+--------------------+
| LEN(0x2020) | DATALENGTH(0x2020) |
+-------------+--------------------+
|           0 |                  2 |
+-------------+--------------------+
```

Though either would work in your use case.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly enough, the two values 0x0 and 0x00 are just different character representations for the same stored value.  Try running the following snippet to prove this to yourself.

```
DECLARE @foo    sql_variant
,  @bar         sql_variant
,  @bat         sql_variant

SET @foo = 0x0
SET @bar = 0x00
SET @bat = 0x00000000

SELECT 'foo' AS 'Var',  @foo                AS 'Value'
,  SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@foo, 'BaseType')   AS 'BaseType'
,  SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@foo, 'Precisionh') AS 'Precision'
,  SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@foo, 'Scale')      AS 'Scale'
,  SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@foo, 'MaxLength')  AS 'MaxLength'
UNION
SELECT 'bar' AS 'Var',  @bar
,  SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@bar, 'BaseType')
,  SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@bar, 'Precisionh')
,  SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@bar, 'Scale')
,  SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@bar, 'MaxLength')
UNION
SELECT 'bat' AS 'Var',  @bat
,  SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@bat, 'BaseType')
,  SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@bat, 'Precisionh')
,  SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@bat, 'Scale')
,  SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@bat, 'MaxLength')

SELECT
   CASE
      WHEN @foo = @bar
      THEN 'equal' 
      ELSE 'NOT EQUAL' 
   END AS TestResults
```

I can understand why the zero padding would surprise people, but that has been the default behavior for a very long time so I guess that I've come to expect it.

-PatP

Comment: Thanks, the 0x0 first appeared in the comments. The question is about 0x and 0x00 (and similar values). Binaries track values on a byte-level so there is no possibility to store half a byte.